# In Psalm 18:24, Does Cleanliness of χειρῶν “Hands” merit righteousness?

Tags: psalms, translation-philosophy, septuagint

Why does LXX version of Psalm 18:24 use the word “χειρῶν” [worse] instead of **“χεῖρας“ [hands] like Job 17:9**, when translating **יָ֝דַ֗י yaday** from Tehillim 18:25?

[Tehillim 18:25, MT]

> “and YHVH has requited me according to my-merit, the cleanness of my-hands in His-Sight.” ( וַיָּֽשֶׁב־יְהֹוָ֣ה לִ֣י כְצִדְקִ֑י כְּבֹ֥ר יָ֝דַ֗י לְנֶ֣גֶד עֵינָֽיו )

[Psalm 18:24, LXX | https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/psa/18/1/t_conc_496024]
“καὶ ἀνταποδώσει μοι κύριος κατὰ τὴν δικαιοσύνην μου καὶ κατὰ τὴν καθαριότητα τῶν **χειρῶν** μου ἐνώπιον τῶν ὀφθαλμῶν αὐτοῦ”

- If χειρῶν can mean “Hands” instead of [worse], how did David merit righteousness in God’s Sight with the cleanliness of his hands?

Comment: See [χειρῶν](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/χειρῶν) and [χείρων](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/χείρων).

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your question about the translator's choice.

As to your second question - "clean hands" is an expression of innocence, as opposed to, say, bloody hands.

David is saying that G-d alone knows of his true innocence and in that merit he will be saved.